# Create XML Datafeed export in PrestaShop

Tags: php, xml, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to export the Products of a presta shop version 1.6.0.11 to an XML file to upload it to google shopping.

I found a post here that shows how to export, but my XML is still empty - is there somebody who knows what could be the issue? I don't get any error.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml/>
```

The files init.php and config.inc.php exist and the code I tried is:

```
<?php
include('config/config.inc.php');
include('init.php'); 
$productObj = new Product();
$products = $productObj -> getProducts($id_lang, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'DESC' );

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
foreach($products as $product) {
    $productXml = $xml->addChild('product');
    $productXml->addChild('id', $product->id);
    $productXml->addChild('name', $product->name);
    $productXml->addChild('description', $product->description);
}
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());

?>
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Be sure you are actually looping through a collection. Syntax looks correct but *$products* could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your $id_lang is not set - just enter integer - your language id.